# htaccess url rewrites and redirects not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website that was updated. I want to make the old urls work, I want to redirect some of them, so links from google search still work, and rewrite the url for other urls, using .htaccess.

For example:

- one rewrite is a.com/services to a.com/consultancy
- one redirect is a.com/services/a/b to a.com/consultancy

One extra comlpication: the site sends every request to /index.php because the URLs are not to physical files, but the index.php script does internal routing, using the requested path, to serve the right content.

I'm not sure if I can do a rewrite (services->consultancy) an then another rewrite (consultancy->index.php) in the same htaccess.

Trying this, I'm getting an internal server error 500 for any URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

#NEW
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^services$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^services$ consultancy [L]

#LEGACY
RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php
```

Also tried the Redirect 301 directive but had no luck, the same error 500.

Any ideas of how to mix rewrites, redirects and the final rewrite to index.php?

Thanks!

#### Update

For the combination of redirect and rewrite I realized some of the rules are a little different than my original question, and those might be causing problems, here is an example:

```
# Redirect to show "consultancy" in the URL
RewriteRule ^services/a/b?$ consultancy [QSA,R,L,NC]

# If "consultancy" is in the URL, change it to the real path
# "consultancy" is an alias of the path that should be processed by index.php
RewriteRule ^consultancy/?$ en/consultoria [NC]

# Should get the "en/consultoria" path
RewriteRule ^ ./index.php [L]
```

The problem with the previous example is that I get the redirect "services/a/b" -> "consultancy" OK, but the rewrite "consultancy" -> "en/consultoria" is not done.

Any ideas?

Comment: 500 is internal server error, check your error log for more info

Comment: If you change `RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php` to `RewriteRule (.*) index.php` it will settle your error 500. `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.` is the error I have in my logs from your config. Overall you probably want to make sure that requests to index.php also don't get rewritten.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusAO which logs are you seeing? apache error.log?

Comment: @PabloPazos yes errors in .htaccess, since they are Apache directives, will be logged in the Apache error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

#rewrite
RewriteRule ^services/?$ consultancy [L,NC]

#redirect
RewriteRule ^services/a/b/?$ consultancy [L,NC,R=302]

#LEGACY
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava that works for the rewrite of /services but is also doing rewrite for the case I need a redirect. The rewrite doesn't issue a redirect. For the redirect, the URL should change from /services/a/b to /consultancy with status 302 or 301 (in fact this is a 301). I tried the Redirect directive but it doesn't work for me. I've read that Redirect and RewriteRule doesn't play well together, and couldn't find one single example of a htaccess file that uses both. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, please see my update, there is one rule where the redirect "destination" should match a rewrite "source", because is an alias of a real path. The redirect is done but not the rewrite.

Comment: **but the rewrite "consultancy" -> "en/consultoria" is not done** How do you know that? Try: `RewriteRule ^consultancy/?$ en/consultoria [NC,L]` also